# handle unreal numbers, jump to catch

Tags: java, math, try-catch

I have this piece of code that is supposed to calculate the root of `f(x) = ln(x+1)+1` using Secant Method.
Having input `xold1 = 0; xold2 = 1;`

```
do {
        try {
            iteration++;
            fxold1 = Math.log(xold1+1)+1;
            fxold2 = Math.log(xold2+1)+1;
            xnew = xold2 - (fxold2 * (xold2 - xold1))/(fxold2 - fxold1);

            //Show iterations and results       
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + iteration + "; x = " + xnew);

            diff = Math.abs(xnew-xold1);

            //Replace old variables with new ones
            xold2 = xold1;
            xold1 = xnew; 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No solution for this starting point.");                
        }
    } while(diff > 0.00001);
```

Output:

```
  Iteration: 1; x = -1.4426950408889634
  Iteration: 2; x = NaN
```

Doing the maths on the paper, the second iteration gives an imaginary number: 0.185125859 + 3.14159265 i. So, the idea was that the program was supposed to jump to catch. why it didn't do so and what I should do to do it? Thank you!

Comment: None of the methods written above throw exceptions, so why would it catch any exception? You need to write a custom exception as per your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easily answered by looking at [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29)

> If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.

`Math.log` doesn't throw an exception if you give it a negative argument. It returns `NaN`. You should [check for that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29) instead of trying to catch an exception.

```
xnew = xold2 - (fxold2 * (xold2 - xold1))/(fxold2 - fxold1);
if(Double.isNaN(xnew)){
    System.out.println("No solution for this starting point.");
    break;
}
```